# Is it possible to run an application as superuser within boot without input?

Tags: 12.04, server, boot, startup, sudo

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop machine running as a server with no input devices accessible after initial setup. I need to place any application that I want to run within the boot process. I have one application that I want to run that requires superuser access to run. Is there a way that I can automate that boot so I don't have to enter my password?

Answer (score 0):

Since Ubuntu uses Upstart, you need to write a custom job for Upstart: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

Processes started during the boot sequence have superuser privileges, so you don't need to bother with `sudo`, passwords and stuff.